# WinForms C# - Display DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress, sql-server-ce

I developped a **WinForms** application where I want to display data through a `DataGridView`. However, the `DataGridView` does not display.

Instead of using multiple forms, I decided to play with `Visible` properties (it was too late when I discovered the "Tabless TabControl" trick because I had already created my panels with my controls inside them.)

**Here is the scenario :**

By default, all my controls are `Visible (=true)`. When I launch the application, the *Home Panel* is displayed. Then by clicking on the search button, the *Home Panel* is hidden by setting its `Visible` property to `false` and the *Search Panel* is shown by setting its `Visible` property to `true`.

**This is fully functional :** my *Search Panel* is shown (tested thanks to a different background color) but my `DataGridView` inside it isn't displayed.

Here is the code:

```
private void iSearch_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mySqlCeEngine.DatabaseExists())
    {
        dgv_customer.DataSource = _mySqlCeEngine.GetCustomers();
        ShowSearchCustomerPanel();

    }
}
```

If the local database file exists, I give a `DataTable` full of data to the `DataGridView` via the `GetCustomers()` method, then show my Search Panel :

```
private void ShowSearchCustomerPanel()
{
        pnl_home.Visible = false;
        pnl_searchCustomer.Visible = true;
}
```

I desperately tried to use `Application.DoEvents()` and/or `dgv_customer.Refresh()` or again re-create the `DataGridView` but nothing is right.

Thanks and sorry for english mistakes if any.

Hellcat.

Comment: Are you sure the Data Grid View is parented to the search panel?

Comment: This is the question I wondered before I decided to re-create the DataGridView by clicking first on the search panel. Is there a reliable way to verify it ?

Comment: Use the View - Other Windows - Document Outline tool to see the hierarchy of your controls.

Comment: I would like to add an information just in case it would be helpful : I do not set a bindingsource/datasource before runtime. It is set via code if the database exists. So before clicking on the search button, the datasource of the DataGridView is "(none)".

Comment: @LarsTech : OMG I didn't know this. It's absolutely wonderful ! But yes, I can see that my DataGridView is the search panel child.

Comment: Okay problem solved.. I didn't realize that my search panel was nested inside the home panel. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the `DataGridView` class which appears if you change the `Visible` property value.

The solution to get through this bug is :

- to remove the `DataGridView` from its parent (with `Controls.Remove()`) to hide it ;
- to readd it to its parent's `Controls` to show it again.